# AP switching time

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router, wireless

I need to ask that how much time is taken in WiFi roaming (switching between the APs).
I am asking about Cisco APs, Cisco outdoor/industrial routers that can connect more than 1000 people, and any other company you people know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a controller to coordinate the associations, handover is very short in order to keep voice call quality acceptable.  Aboslutely not for 1,000 users but without a controller you can see 1 second dropouts routinely.  Badly organised controllers in public spaces can easily be observed to drop out for much longer, perhaps 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you know any of the wireless LAN controllers?
Do you have any knowledge on Cisco Aironet 1572EAC AP? On the website it is stated that more than 1500 devices can connect to it.

Comment: I don't know that particular device but the max connections limit of software is normally way higher than the max with acceptable bandwidth/user in any particular situation.  If you you have 1,000 users you need to work on the bandwidth budgets and management throughout your network.